# Expected count of "double records"

Tags: probability

I was doing a problem involving athletes competing at the high jump, with the `j`th jumper achieving height $X_j$, with $i = 1..n$ and $X_i$ i.i.d. from a continuous distribution. We say the $j$th jumper sets a record if $X_j > X_i$ for $i = 1..j-1$. The question is to calculate the expected number of "double records" among the first $n$ jumpers, with a "double record" occurring at time $j$ if both the $j$th and $j-1$th jumpers set records.

The solution is pretty straightforward - we calculate $\sum_1^n P(R_j)$ where $P(R_j)$ is the probability that a double record occurs at $j$. It assumes that the events $R_j$ are independent -- I don't think this is true, though. Isn't it the case that $P(R_j|R_{j-1}) = 1/j > P(R_j)$?

Comment: I'm not sure why $P(R_j|R_{j-1})$ should be $1/j$, but I do agree that they don't seem independent.

Answer (score 0):

Thought about it a bit more and now it seems like a dumb question -- the expectation of the sum is just the sum of expectations regardless of whether the variables are independent.

Answer (score 0):

The probability the $j$th jump is an individual new record is $\frac1j$ and it is independent of how many previous records there have been and which ones they were. But this is not the case with double records as the event $R_{j-1}$ requires the $j-1$th jump to have been a record and so increases the chance of the event $R_j$

You have $P(R_j \mid R_{j-1}) = \frac1j$ for $j \ge 1$, as you say

and $P(R_j)=\frac{1}{(j-1)j}=\frac1{j-1}-\frac1j$ for $j \gt 1$, and this is greater than $P(R_j \mid R_{j-1})$ when $j \gt2$

but, as you also say, this does not matter as you can use linearity of expectation

The expected number of double records is then $\sum\limits_{j=2}^n P(R_j) = 1 -\frac1n$